# RNA extraction from soil

Tags: rna-sequencing, soil

I have been trying to extract RNA from soil without success. I have used commercial kits (The Plant DNeasy kit) because I did not want to buy a complete new kit (Soil) to do 5 extractions. Is there any "in-house" protocol that successfully extracts RNA from the soil? Or, is there any tip that would allow me to extract good soil RNA using the Plant DNeasy kit?
Thanks